# Set Kafka log directory property in Windows

Tags: windows, logging, log4j, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When I was running a kafka broker on Windows system, I always got this error: 
 `log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\kafka/logs/server.log] to [C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\kafka/logs/server.log.2017-09-20-09].`

You can see there are some "/" and "\". So I believe the problem is caused by the log4j directory setting. Is there anyone met similar problem, may I ask how can I solve this problem?

My settings:

zookeeper - > log4j.properties:

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
zookeeper.root.logger=INFO, CONSOLE
zookeeper.console.threshold=INFO
zookeeper.log.dir=.
zookeeper.log.file=zookeeper.log
zookeeper.log.threshold=DEBUG
zookeeper.tracelog.dir=.
zookeeper.tracelog.file=zookeeper_trace.log

#
# ZooKeeper Logging Configuration
#

# Format is "<default threshold> (, <appender>)+

# DEFAULT: console appender only
log4j.rootLogger=${zookeeper.root.logger}

# Example with rolling log file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE, ROLLINGFILE

# Example with rolling log file and tracing
#log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, CONSOLE, ROLLINGFILE, TRACEFILE

#
# Log INFO level and above messages to the console
#
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L] - %m%n

#
# Add ROLLINGFILE to rootLogger to get log file output
#    Log DEBUG level and above messages to a log file
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.Threshold=${zookeeper.log.threshold}
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=${zookeeper.log.dir}/${zookeeper.log.file}

# Max log file size of 10MB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
# uncomment the next line to limit number of backup files
#log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L] - %m%n


#
# Add TRACEFILE to rootLogger to get log file output
#    Log DEBUG level and above messages to a log file
log4j.appender.TRACEFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.TRACEFILE.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.TRACEFILE.File=${zookeeper.tracelog.dir}/${zookeeper.tracelog.file}

log4j.appender.TRACEFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
### Notice we are including log4j's NDC here (%x)
log4j.appender.TRACEFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L][%x] - %m%n
```

Kafka -> log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the two lines below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Change to DEBUG to enable audit log for the authorizer
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=WARN, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

Kafka -> server.properties:

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
delete.topic.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=.\logs\kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=2

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Version:

Windows 10, 
Kafka 2.11-0.11.0.0, 
Zookeeper 3.4.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change `log.dirs=.\logs\kafka-logs` to use forward slash (`log.dirs=./logs/kafka-logs`).

Seems Kafka does't like backslash at config files

Comment: And where do we find this so called `server.properties` file? My Kafka broker is located in a linux machine and my windows machine acts as a kafka client.

Answer (score 0):

I think deletion of topic fails due to Java's **File.rename** function. It works differently in some cases in Windows environment (for example if file is in use). Kafka developers already changed this function to **Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback** (see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3105) for details), but seems it was not included into Kafka 2.11-0.11.0. So you need to work with Kafka version that has this fix. Hope this will help you.